# Ways of using adverbs in the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Actually, you have several variants using adverbs in sentences. Take for example "unlikely" adverb to express scenario that is not likely to happen. We can put it to the subordinate close at the beginning of the sentence or place it with the verb, like this:

> It is unlikely you'll need to use them at the moment.
>
> You'll unlikely need to use them at the moment.

The question is what the difference between 2 options? Are there other ways how we can express that idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not difference in meaning between the two sentences. They mean the same, though the last sentence was a bit clunky. It was grammatically correct, yet I would never write it, due to the awkward use of *unlikely*. Though, this is not a site for writing advice.

As for other alternatives, I have listed a few;

> It is improbable that you'll need to use them at the moment.
>
> You'll probably not have to use them at the moment.

They're not perfect, but their valid options. And I know this is not a writing advice site, but I'll have to give you this advice: **Forget about the sentence and write! Making your story is more important.**